# Como capturar el evento close de un MessageBox

Tags: c, winapi

Tengo la duda de saber si se puede capturar el evento `Close` de un `MessageBox`.

Claramente la aplicacion corre en windows

CODIGO:

```
MessageBox(0,"Title","description",1);
```

Ahora esta funcionando es decir salta un `MessageBox` en la pantalla pero me gustaría poder llamar otra función cuando el usuario lo cierre o le de `OK`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx), `MessageBox` retorna un `int` que puede tener los siguientes valores:

- IDABORT: Se ha pulsado el botón *abortar*
- IDCANCEL: Se ha pulsado el botón *cancelar* o la tecla *ESC*
- IDCONTINUE: Se ha pulsado el botón *continuar*
- IDIGNORE: Se ha pulsado el botón *ignorar*
- IDNO: Se ha pulsado el botón *no*
- IDOK: Se ha pulsado el botón *ok*
- IDRETRY: Se ha pulsado el botón *reintentar*
- IDTRYAGAIN: Se ha pulsado el botón *intentar de nuevo*
- IDYES: Se ha pulsado el botón *sí*

En cualquier caso, la llamada es bloqueante, es decir el hilo de ejecución no abandona la función hasta que no se ha cerrado la ventana modal, así pues para ejecutar algo cuando la ventana se cierre basta con poner el código justo después de la llamada a la función:

```
MessageBox(0,"Title","description",1);
std::cerr << "Se acaba de cerrar la ventana modal";
```

Si, en cambio, quieres actuar en función del botón pulsado por el usuario:

```
int res = MessageBox(0,"Title","description",1);

switch( res )
{
  case IDCANCEL:
    /* ... El usuario presiona cancelar o ESC ... */
    break;

  case IDOK:
    /* ... El usuario presiona el boton OK ... */
    break;
}
```

Comment: Exacto, gracias amigo, me funciono. En mi caso tengo un while loopeado digamos , es decir nunca termina excepto cuando el  user le da ok al msgbox en ese caso hace el break, deporcierto en C el ok retorna 1 y los cancel retornan 2 ;)

Comment: @WhySoBizarreCode he rechazado la edición porque el comentario no es para nada cierto. Ese valor no es dependiente de C sino de la api de windows... es decir, en otras versiones de Windows el valor podría cambiar (generalmente no va a ser así... pero las macros están precisamente para desligarte de números mágicos y es preferible dejarlo así)

Comment: A muchisimas gracias por explicarme amigo, disculpa mi ignorancia aun tengo mucho que aprender y pense que te referias a C++ en tu code ;)